# Finding the point of intersection with vectors

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, vectors

I'm trying to solve the following problem to no avail:

Let  $_1()=⟨8,−5,1⟩+⟨0,−1,−4⟩$  and  $_2()=⟨12,−3,5⟩+⟨1,0,−1$⟩.  Find the point of intersection,  $$,  of the two lines  $_1$  and  $_2$.

I've tried adding them together to their directional vectors, so
$r_1(t) =⟨8,-5-t,1-4t⟩$ and $r_2⟨12+s,-3,5-1s⟩$.

Now would I like subtract them or something? I don't know what to do now. Any ideas?

Comment: if these two lines are intersect they have a  intersection point that point lies on both lines so you can get that point as $<a,b,c>$ then tried to get system of equation and solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to calculate the intersection, you have to solve the linear equation system

\begin{align}
8 + 0t &= 12 + 1s \\
-5 -1t &= -3 + 0s \\
1 -4t &= 5 - 1s
\end{align}

for $(t, s)$. Then plug one value into the corresponding line equation.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: oh yea i can do that! thanks brother